# Does SQL Server 2019 have task scheduling differences between enterprise and standard editions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, database-internals

In [How It Works: SQL Server 2012 Database Engine Task Scheduling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/how-it-works-sql-server-2012-database-engine-task-scheduling), Bob Dorr explains some of the changes for worker scheduler assignment in SQL Server 2012. He mentions that some of the improvements are only available in enterprise edition. Do these differences persist in SQL Server 2019?

If it matters, I'm asking because I'm seeing possible scheduler inefficiencies on a SQL Server 2017 standard edition instance which has a planned future upgrade to enterprise edition. I don't want to attempt an investigation on standard edition if it's possible that upgrading to enterprise will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In that Bob Dorr article, when he mentions that the improvements are only available in Enterprise Edition, he hints at the reason.

> The EE [Enterprise Edition] SKU has been updated to further accommodate *CPU resource governance*.

The implication here is that the resource governance feature is necessary in order to do the new-style task/worker scheduling. From later in that document:

> Instead of using the traditional, task count based load factor a CPU resource targeting load factor is used for the task assignments.

If resource governance is required for the improved scheduling algorithm, it comes down to which editions of SQL 2019 include it. Per [this edition guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15), the Resource Governor feature is only available in Enterprise Edition.